# Valid Bogoliubov transformation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory

Is it possible to diagonalize the Hamiltonian:
$H=c_1 c_2^\dagger+c_2 c_1^\dagger +\delta(c_1c_2+c_2^\dagger c_1^\dagger ) $ using the Bogoliubov canonical transformation, where the $c_1,c_2$ are standard fermion anihilation operators...?

I tried 
$\begin{bmatrix}
    c_{1}  \\
    c_{2}   
\end{bmatrix}$ 
$=$
$\begin{bmatrix}
    x &-y  \\
    y &x   
\end{bmatrix}$ 
$\begin{bmatrix}
    d_{1}  \\
    d_{2}^\dagger   
\end{bmatrix}$ 
and

$\begin{bmatrix}
    c_{1}  \\
    c_{2}^\dagger   
\end{bmatrix}$ 
$=$
$\begin{bmatrix}
    x &-y  \\
    y &x   
\end{bmatrix}$ 
$\begin{bmatrix}
    d_{1}  \\
    d_{2}   
\end{bmatrix}$

At the end I allways get terms like: $x^2 d_1 d_2 ^\dagger -y^2 d_2^\dagger d_1 +x^2 d_1 d_2 -y^2 d_2^\dagger d_1^\dagger+h.c.$. In order for the Hamiltonian to be diagonal I require: $x^2 d_1 d_2 ^\dagger -y^2 d_2^\dagger d_1 +x^2 d_1 d_2 -y^2 d_2^\dagger d_1^\dagger+h.c.=0$ The problem is that there is no connection between let's say: $d_1d_2^\dagger $ and $d_2^\dagger d_1^\dagger$ in terms of anticommutation relations. Can I try something like this:
$\begin{bmatrix}
    c_{1}  \\
    c_{2}   
\end{bmatrix}$ 
$=$
$\begin{bmatrix}
    x &-y  \\
    y &x   
\end{bmatrix}$ 
$\begin{bmatrix}
    d_{1}  \\
    d_{2}   
\end{bmatrix}$ 
or does this transformation not preserve the canonical anticommutation relations(CAR)?